# Как лучше поступить при взаимодействии двух классов в Python

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Хочу самостоятельно написать игру "Покер" в терминале, но с мультиплеером через **socket**. Вроде бы не трудно, но код получается очень запутанным, и вдруг я встретился с ситуацией, в которой один класс использует функции другого, как лучше поступить, передать объект класса **GameServer** через аргумент:

```
class Game():
...
    def players_move(self, player: player.Player, 
                     client: Client, server: GameServer):

        ...
```

Или лучше создать объект этого класса внутри другого класса, что даже звучит уже странно, если честно:

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.game_server = GameServer()
    ....
    
    def players_move(self, player: player.Player, client: Client):
        ...
```

Хоть оно и звучит странно, но я всё же не уверен в правильности одного из них, а может и ни одно неправильно.
Под правильностью я имею ввиду красоту и простоту кода

Comment: Лично мне понятнее второй вариант.

Comment: Честно. Я бы в Game делал все, что связано с игрой - т.е. GameServer. А в GameServer уже делал бы управление игроком, ведь вне игрового сервера в онлайн игре существовать игроки не могут

Comment: @RottenRat в моём случае GameServer отвечает за подключение игроков, отправку информации игрокам и т.п., а Game содержит в себе игровую логику, которая как раз таки и будет использовать функции по типу отправки и получения информации от игроков :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> создать объект этого класса внутри другого класса, что даже звучит уже
> странно

нормально звучит, у этого подхода даже есть название - "композиция классов".

Если у вас по логике кода подразумевается, что экземпляр GameServer всегда относится к определённому экземпляру класса Game, то как раз лучше создавать его внутри.

Answer (score 2):

Есть ещё средний вариант. Когда все объекты создаются где-то снаружи, в определённом порядке и в определённой зависимости друг от друга. `DI` фреймворк какой-нибудь опять же для этого можно использовать, чтобы объекты конфигом создавались.

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self, server: GameServer):
        ...
        self.game_server = server
```